# Get a file from the application directory

Tags: android, file, path, directory, android-file

I need to get a file from the application directory.
I have a folder of images, and the path (in the pc application folder) is:

```
blablablablabla/<ApplicationName>/images/
```

To help you understand, at the same level we find

```
blablablablabla/<ApplicationName>/res/

blablablablabla/<ApplicationName>/src/

ecc ecc
```

I need to get the file from that folder (images) and not from the res folder.

I found somewhere that I can get the path of the data application this way:

```
context.getPackageManager()
                .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0)
                .applicationInfo.dataDir;
```

and this path is something like:

```
 data/data/<ApplicationName>/
```

where should i put my folder "images" to find it in

```
 data/data/<ApplicationName>/images/
```

?

If you know other ways to avoid the problem that don't include to put my images in the res folder or to use external card, they're accepeted. Thank you =)

Comment: Wat you want is impossible. Put your files in assets directory or res/raw or res/drawable. Then at runtime copy to internal or external memory or load from actual resource.

Comment: `the path (in the pc application folder)` what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

> I have a folder of images, and the path (in the pc application folder) is: blablablablabla//images/

Nothing in the Android development tools will pay any attention to that directory, and its contents will not be in the APK.

> where should i put my folder "images" to find it in

You are welcome to download files from the Internet and put them in `new File(getFilesDir(), "images")` if you want.

Or, you are welcome to put the images in your `assets/` directory, and use them straight from there, if you will only be reading (not writing) the images.

Or, you are welcome to put the images in your `assets/` directory, and copy them to `new File(getFilesDir(), "images")`.